# mysql procedure with custom 'table-like' output

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

This may or may not be a simple question.

I am looking for a way to NOT select anything from a table, but return a set of table-like data.

Basically I have a procedure that loops through a table and stores data into a variable, then displays it by the line:

```
SELECT @args as parents;
```

Is there any better way to set up a table data structure and return that whole thing? Right now I am returning a single variable with multiple (parse-needed) data.

EDIT:

To try and explain better:

What I have to do is loop through and perform a series of select statements, is there a way to 'concat' this data into a big datatable structure and then return that table?

Comment: maybe i need to explain myself better. I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a temp table

```
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;
   CREATE TABLE tmp( --fields-- );   
   WHILE ( --condition-- ) DO
       INSERT INTO tmp VALUES ( --fields-- );
       SELECT --Statement--
   END WHILE;


--do stuff--
```

and clean up

```
DROP TABLE tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive for mySQL, but you should be able to use a function to return a table.  I found the following on another question, which might be helpful:

```
CREATE FUNCTION getdepartments() 
    RETURNS @departments TABLE( 
        DNAME VARCHAR(25), 
        DEPTID VARCHAR(10), 
        DBONUS DECIMAL(7,2)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    INSERT @departments SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENT; 
    RETURN 
END
```

I've done this in SQL Server, and you can do fun things like recursive functions that keep adding records to your output table, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could return a recordset like described here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?102,50520,50626#msg-50626. Hope that this will help.